# FFMPEG: hls_flags append_list not working

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am taking rtmp stream as input and converting into HLS using ffmpeg. However append_list option is not working. Following is the ffmpeg command I am using

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/hls/session -codec copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -map 0 -f hls -hls_time 2 -hls_flags +append_list index.m3u8
```

Above command is throwing following error

```
[hls muxer @ 0x105b760] [Eval @ 0x7ffeae5b4530] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'append_list'
[hls muxer @ 0x105b760] Unable to parse option value "append_list"
[hls muxer @ 0x105b760] Error setting option hls_flags to value +append_list.
Output #0, hls, to 'index.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 672
    displayHeight   : 378
    fps             : 29
    profile         : 
    level           : 
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 672x378 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2191 kb/s, 29.42 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29 tbn, 29 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

Comment: `ffmpeg`s version?

Comment: ffmpeg version is 3.0

Comment: you need 3.2.9 or later for `append_list`